# Alternatives for thesis if companies don't respond for interview requests? How to still make it academically relevant?

Tags: research-process, thesis, masters

The thesis I intend to do is trying to understand how different public transport companies perceive the concept of sharing economy in the EU: Do these public transport companies treat companies moving towards a sharing economy as a threat or would they like to collaborate with them?

However, I can only proceed with this idea if the companies respond to the questions/agree for an interview. In the thesis proposal, my subject reader want's to know how this thesis can be done scientifically/academically if none of the companies will respond. I am stuck with how to respond or proceed with this. Any ideas that could be suggested?

Comment: What is the 'sharing economy' and why do public transport companies care?

Comment: Can you pursue something else? This seems like a hard one to convince people about.

Comment: Kind of sounds like a single item in a survey (that's unlikely to be returned; companies don't have opinions they make business decisions), not a thesis.

Comment: I don't know your subject, but it may be that if they don't respond, you do not have a project. This is a significant risk that you should develop a contingency plan for - and that is what the question is meant to make you do.

Comment: When this closed, I was halfway through writing an answer along the lines of "plan your workflow so that, if the companies are not going to respond, you'll find that out a long, long way in advance of the thesis submission deadline, so you'll have time to devise a different project."  Is there a project management stack?

Answer (score 1):

I think your reader is right to question your methodology.

If the companies don't respond (as is likely) you will have to deduce their perceptions from their visible actions.

You will have to look at those actions in any case.

If that data is not available you need a different topic.